# Using tuples as dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, tuples

The commented block of code below outputs my desired answer whilst the uncommented block outputs the wrong answers.

Could somebody shed light on why the two blocks of code are different? The keys to self.q should be (state, action) pairs, so why does self.q[state][action] work? Shouldn't self.q only accept one key?

```
    def update_q_value(self, state, action, old_q, reward, future_rewards):
        # Q-values are stored in the dictionary self.q. The keys of self.q should be in the form of (state, action) pairs, where state is a tuple of all piles sizes in order, and action is a tuple (i, j) representing a pile and a number.

        state_pair = (tuple(state), action)
        if state_pair not in self.q:
            self.q[state_pair] = dict()

        print(old_q + self.alpha * (reward + future_rewards - old_q))

        self.q[state_pair] = old_q + self.alpha * (reward + future_rewards - old_q)

        # state = tuple(state)
        # if state not in self.q:
        #     self.q[state] = dict()

        # print(old_q + self.alpha * (reward + future_rewards - old_q))

        # self.q[state][action] = old_q + self.alpha * (reward + future_rewards - old_q)
```

Output from the first block looks like this:

```
Playing training game 1
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-0.5
0.5
Playing training game 2
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-0.75
0.75
...
Playing training game 9999
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
1.0
Playing training game 10000
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-1.0
1.0
```

Output from the second block looks like this:

```
Playing training game 1
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-0.5
0.5
Playing training game 2
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
-0.25
-0.5
0.5
...
Playing training game 9999
0.0625
0.125
0.125
0.125
0.25
0.25
-0.25
-0.5
0.5
Playing training game 10000
0.0625
0.125
0.125
0.125
0.25
0.25
-0.25
-0.5
0.5
```

The full code is here if anyone is willing to look at it: https://d.pr/n/MKE8iH It can be run with something like:

```
ai = train(10000)
play(ai)
```

Comment: Could you add a few examples of _how_ the second implementation gives the wrong answer? i.e. input and output values to the two different functions.

Comment: `self.q[state_pair]` has the tuple as key. `self.q[state][action]` is a dict in a dict

Comment: @MatsLindh Edited the post to clarify how the second implementation gives the wrong answer. It's part of an ML algorithm to play Nim.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer It's odd though because when I try to access it, like through ```print(self.q[state][action])```, it gives me a KeyError for the action value.

Comment: @JasonC Sorry, but your example doesn't show anything useful for helping debug the actual function call; simplify it to only show three sets of inputs and the correct and wrong input _to the function itself_. It's impossible for us to say anything about what happens behind the scenes in your larger application. Narrow down your problem to the lines you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `self.q[state][action]` works because you are creating another dictionary as value, which has `action` as key.

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.qTuple = {}
        self.qDict = {}

    def update_q_value_tuple(self, state, action, value):
        state_pair = (tuple(state), action)
        if state_pair not in self.qTuple:
            self.qTuple[state_pair] = dict()
        self.qTuple[state_pair] = value


    def update_q_value_dict(self, state, action, value):
        state = tuple(state)
        if state not in self.qDict:
            self.qDict[state] = dict()
        self.qDict[state][action] = value


f = foo()
states = ['foo', 'bar']
actions = ['hold', 'release']

for s in states:
    for a in actions:
        for v in range(0, 5):
            f.update_q_value_tuple(s, a, v)
            f.update_q_value_dict(s, a, v)

print f.qTuple
print f.qDict
```

Output:

```
{(('f', 'o', 'o'), 'hold'): 4, (('b', 'a', 'r'), 'hold'): 4, (('b', 'a', 'r'), 'release'): 4, (('f', 'o', 'o'), 'release'): 4}
{('f', 'o', 'o'): {'release': 4, 'hold': 4}, ('b', 'a', 'r'): {'release': 4, 'hold': 4}}
```

Note, you need to be careful when creating a tuple with one element dont forget to a trailing comma: `state = tuple(state, )`